# My keyboard is randomly changing causing space key to not working

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout

HP Pavilion Gaming Notebook - 15-ak031tx
Os Info:
   Linux 5.3.0-45-generic
   Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Description: 
   My space key works on and off, while certain keys when pressed produce unintended results. For instance, I use to turn on my the backlit by simply pressing f5, instead gives this ~ and can turn it on when I press shift + f5.

Comment: Please test with another keyboard so we can see if this is a hardware or software issue.

Comment: I don't have one at home and right now, we are in lockdown, so, I can't go out get one.